# Ability to choose between multiple PDF templates on a Netsuite transaction form

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

We'd like to have a drop down list of pdf templates to choose from on our sales order.  I tried to create a suitelet that does this but I'm kind of lost in how to get the pdf forms to actually pull up and populate with information specific to that transaction.  Right now I just get the pop up and two option to choose from, neither option pulls anything up.

```
function suitelet(request, response) {
      var recordId = request.getParameter('id'); // get the ID of the Proposal record
      var pdf1FileId = "138"; // replace with the ID of the PDF file for the first form
      var pdf2FileId = "139"; // replace with the ID of the PDF file for the second form
    
      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'recordId', recordId);
      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'pdf1FileId', pdf1FileId);
      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'pdf2FileId', pdf2FileId);
    
      var html = '<html>';
      html += '<head>';
      html += '<title>Select PDF</title>';
      html += '</head>';
      html += '<body>';
      html += '<h2>Select PDF to Print:</h2>';
      html += '<button onclick="openPDF(\'' + pdf1FileId + '\',\'' + recordId + '\',\'' + response +     '\')">PDF Option 1</button>';
      html += '<button onclick="openPDF(\'' + pdf2FileId + '\',\'' + recordId + '\',\'' + response + '\')">PDF Option 2</button>';
      html += '</body>';
      html += '</html>';

      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'html', html);

      response.write(html); // write the HTML to the response
    }

    function openPDF(fileId, recordId, response) {
      var file = nlapiLoadFile(fileId); // load the PDF file

      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'fileId', fileId);
      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'recordId', recordId);
      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'file', file);

      var url = file.getURL(); // get the URL of the PDF file

      url += '&id=' + recordId; // pass the ID of the Proposal record as a parameter

      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'url', url);

      response.sendRedirect(url); // redirect the user to the PDF URL
    }

    function onRequest(context) {
      var request = context.request;
      var response = context.response;

      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'request method', request.method);

      if (request.method === 'GET') {
        suitelet(request, response); // call the suitelet function when the Suitelet is accessed via HTTP GET
      }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like some cookbook code copied from somewhere and doesn't really match what you write that you are trying to do. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: i wrote most of it lol and tried to write beside it what I wanted to happen lol.   basically, I have a sales order, we have to print out multiple pdfs to send to clients based on a variety of factors.  Instead of using a ton of if statements on 1 pdf, I want to pull in 3 templates I have created into some kind of list our users can choose from and print.  The suitelet I built had the link I could click on and it would show different clickable options.  I never got to a point where those options lead somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

At it's simplest if your users have the ability to select different transaction forms then each form can have its own HTML/PDF template. If the form is sticky ("Store Form with Record" is checked) then when the record is saved with the new form printing that record will print with the form's template.

If that doesn't work then you are faced with using the `N/render` module.

Similarly to selecting a form you can call `render.transaction({entityId:transactionid, formId:formId})` to get Netsuite to render the PDF using formId's HTML/PDF template.

If setting up different forms to handle this is not the route you want to go you can look into using `N/render.templateRenderer`. You can generally save your transaction HTML/PDF templates to the file cabinet and use them for arbitrary PDF generation (arbitrary from the point of view that you can add record sources that the form based templates will balk at).